# Use external product image link in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using web scraper to scrape products from other website and import it to my wordpress site. It is uploading images on my server but i don't want it to import images instead want to directly use external link of image. Is it possible to use external image link for woocommerce products without downloading images to the server?

Comment: Please share some code. That will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: updated question i guess it is better to understand now

Comment: Currently having the same issue came across this plugin but do not yet know if it works with WooCommerce APIs well 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-from-url/